# Prevent jquery mobile to change behavior of links

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, jquery-mobile

So I list a bunch of wordpress posts, and when I click on a title, jquery loads the single post page form me via ajax, I guess, and I don't want that, I just want the normal behavior of a link, I tried this:

```
      $('article a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //also possible
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

But doesn't work, I also tried `data-role="none"`and `data-enhance="false"`on `<a>` but still no success.

I mean, I could listen for the click with jquery, and do a `window.location` but this will be sick to do so.

Any solutions guys?

Comment: How is the AJAX bound to the links? I would find where that code is and change it right there if mobile. Have the function not run the AJAX and return true which will then just go to the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Solved like this:

```
$('article a').click(function(event){
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the normal behavior of a link, have you tried `data-ajax="false"` inside `a` tag?

```
<a href="#home" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-transition="slide" data-inline="true"  data-ajax="false">Home</a>
```